# header redirect $_SESSION empty

Tags: php, session, redirect, location

I have the following scripts:
login.php

```
 session_start();
    #login procedure (not relevant)
    if (login(..)) {
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $foo;
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;

        session_write_close();

        var_dump($_SESSION); //=> works properly

        header('location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
```

index.php

```
session_start();
include( 'core/auth.php');

//..
```

auth.php

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION); //=> EMPTY (!)
```

So it seems like the session variables are getting lost during the redirection.
Is it a server configuration problem?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this on localhost ?

Comment: why aren't the double `session_start()` calls creating errors?

Comment: `if ( ! session_id()) session_start();` use that in `core/auth.php`

Comment: @Dale no clue. I replaced it with your code.

Comment: all of a sudden it works. Thanks! Guess it was a server issue..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 'file' as the PHP session save handler(**session.save_handler** variable in php.ini), check that the user hosting the PHP process (likely apache, or nginx)  has write permissions on the save path.(**session.save_path**)